# create c# project at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Does any body know how can I create a C# project at runtime, add classes to it and compile it to generate a dll.

Comment: Do you need a visual-studio project, or just to compile the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to compile code and generate a dll, see cdhowie's answer.

If you want to have a complete project file at the end, you can create a csproj file through XML or Text output, which points to the code (and other) files you want to include, then execute "msbuild myproject.csproj".

Open a .csproj file for a project you have with notepad, the structure isn't complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in creating dynamic classes for your own use the have a look at [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.aspx) namespace. You can create assembly full of types on the fly.